# request error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Operation could not be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)"

Tags: iphone

I am working on IN App purchase, storekit.

I am getting this error:

> request error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Operation could not be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)"

What does this means?

Comment: Did you solve the problem, because I'm facing the exact same thing?

Comment: are u trying to test ur app on device or simlulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Operation could not be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664778/error-domain-skerrordomain-code-0-operation-could-not-be-completed-skerrordom)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes when you have bad internet connection, it returns that error because the app cannot communicate with the apple server. Just try to retry or if you have another internet connection source, try connecting there then do what you want again.

Answer (score 4):

use device for testing not simulator

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, testing ON the device. I'm guessing that a lot of the time this is the cause of that particular error, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the device worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This was happening on the Simulator and just closing the simulator and re-opening seemed to fixed it