# Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Operation could not be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)”

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm working with In App Purchase. I'm trying to get all my transactions from AppleStore. After request, I catch an error code:

request error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Operation could not be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)”

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

I have not even enter my user credentials. How to fix it? Whats a problem? Anybody know?
PS: I'm testing it on iPad and iPhone devices - not Simulator. Thanx!

[image]

Comment: See an other answer for the same error : [iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891548/skerrordomain-code-0-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You must logout from your iTunes account in the settings app. Then try again and use a test account. You can create them in the iTunes connect page.

Comment: Incredible... :)