# In App purchases not working

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, mkstorekit

I am in a strange situation. I have around 200 in app purchases in my application. Some I am able to test while for others i keep on getting SKErrorDomain error with error code =0. Since I am able to test few products, I guess the problem is not with the code.
I have followed the checklist for testing in app purchases- my build number and version are not blank, i have double checked the spellings of the product identifiers. I have also tried reseting the device but all in vain.All the in apps are cleared for sale.
Can anyone guess what probably could be wrong with the settings or the code? Also I would like to know if there is any upper limit to the number of in apps that can be put in an application?

PS : I am using MKStoreKit

Comment: Are create sandbox(test) account in Apple Site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create up to 10000 in-app purchases per app.

> You can create up to 10,000 separate product IDs assigned to your
>   in-app purchases per app in iTunes Connect. This number refers to the
>   number of in-app purchases, not the number of purchase transactions.

and i think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664778/error-domain-skerrordomain-code-0-operation-could-not-be-completed-skerrordom) will solve your issue

Comment: I am using a test user account for testing the in app purchases. I guess the only option left is to create new ids for in apps that are not working. Strange!