# SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My application has just gone live on the iTunes Store, and after that, I am unable to start any purchase. I have tested the application and its working fine in Sandbox envoirnemnt. But Live application gives the error

`Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store`

`enum value = SKErrorUnknown`

I have tried signing out any test accounts from Store login, but it just doesn't ask for any account login and error keeps on coming. Any clue!

Comment: Have you used XCode `Capabilities` tab ?

Comment: I have just checked the Capabilities, In-App Purchases are On against the App ID (on Dev Portal). But still its behaving in same way. I have observed a crash though with the following message:
"NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot finish a purchasing transaction'" 

But I am explicitly finishing all the pending transaction before i add new one in the SKPaymentQueue.

Comment: what is Capabilities tab? @Vinzzz

Answer (score 17):

This can happen because of the two problems i guess.

- Make sure you have placed the correct "Product Identifier".If that's the case, then you'll get error 0 shortly after calling -[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:], before you get the popup asking you to confirm payment.
- Your test user has become invalidated. This can happen if you accidentally log into the App Store with your test user. When this happens, you'll get error 0 after entering your password to confirm your payment.

To fix problem #1, pass in the correct product ID. To fix problem #2, create a new test user on iTunes Connect, and optionally delete the old test user.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I was getting this error. Double checked my request and realized I was sending an empty set of identifiers. Corrected that and the error went away. Thanks!

Comment: Just as an addendum - you can still see this error *before* you *manually* enter your password to confirm your payment when the problem is related to your test user. To fix this - I created a new test user and then went to Settings on the device, went to iTunes & App Store, and signed out of the iTunes account with my old user and the error went away.

Comment: In my error this error happens `after trying to upgrade a plan`. https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils/issues/205. I'm using a sanbox tester.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error while testing subscriptions, was able to get it to work by adding a Localization (Subscription Display Name
  and Description) to the product from iTunes connect.

Comment: This is actually very important information, and it was exactly what happened in my case. There is no obvious way to see this from the error and you may quickly miss it, when you are preparing placeholders for future In-App Purchases.

Comment: @I-I hi ,can you say more about how to add a Localization (Subscription Display Name and Description) to the product from iTunes connect?

Comment: In the page where you can edit the in-app purchase you can find a section called "App Store Information". In this section you can add the localizations. You need to have at least one for it to work.

Comment: This comment is a bit of a rant, but I'm sorry. This is absolutely insane. How can apple not mention this in its documentation? And why would they allow developers to test the subscriptions without a display name if it causes such a vague issue? I've been struggling with this same issue for so long now. I'm sure it's not hard for them to implement a different errorcode that tells us that there is missing metadata.

Anyway, thanks so much for this. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

Check if you sign out of the iTunes Store.
To sign out, follow these steps:

1. Open the Settings App
2. Tap the “Store” row
3. Tap “Sign Out”

Answer (score 2):

you can check few things and verify it.

`Verify following things` :

`(1)` your App's `Bundle ID`. it should be same as you created in iTunes store in which you have added In App Purchases.

`(2)` Check Your `In App Identifier` Name, which you use in Application.

If any of these is not matching it would throw `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store` exception.

Comment: hi , how to check the In App Identifier Name?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario was exactly mine. After addPayment was called, a dialog box popped up saying "Log in to the iTunes store with an existing or new account". As soon as I selected Login, I got the error above.

I had reinitialised my iPad and signed out of iCloud. No luck. Then, showing a friend, found that there is also an iTunes a& AppStore sign out option which is distinct from this.  Clicked on the Touch Id line and it offered me a sign out option. Then, I was prompted to login with a test account on making a purchase. It worked!

Answer (score -3):

in your Xcode:

1. Click on your active scheme name right next to the Stop button
2. Click on Edit Scheme....
3. in Run (Debug) select the Arguments tab
4. in Environment Variables click +
5. add variable: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

Comment: when you test with sandbox user, you need to do the above setting first.