# Cannot connect to iTunes Store (Code=0) when purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription

I have setup all necessary (bundleId, iTunesConnect stuff, banking info) and still getting connection error when trying to purchase a subscription.
What am I missing? 
The only thing I still didn't check is the state of subscription (it's Ready to submit at the moment).
Do I need to submit subscription to review in order to be able to test it?

Answer (score 0):

No need to submit subscription to review.
Please check Contact Info, Bank Info and Tax Info in Tax & Agreement section in iTunes.
You can check the IAP with sandbox user only during the development process.

Please follow this [LINK](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) for more information.

Comment: Also, refer this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891548/skerrordomain-code-0-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store

Comment: I've discovered one strange thing. The purchase is working fine on devices with iOS of version lower than 11

Comment: Are you using any IAP manager or coded by your self? if used any manager/helper library reply with it's name in comment.

Comment: I'm using SwiftyStoreKit, also I tried self-coded approach